# Same value was passed as the nextKey in two sequential Pages loaded from a PagingSource in Paging Library 3 Android

Tags: android-studio, rx-java2, paging

I migrated from paging 2 to paging 3. I tried to implement ItemKeyedDataSource of Paging 2 to Paging library 3. But the problem I was facing is, the same value(currentJodId) was passed as the nextkey in two sequential Pages loaded. And After that app crashes. but if I add "keyReuseSupported = true" in DataSource, app does not crash. But it started calling same item id as the nextkey.

`JobSliderRestApi.kt`

```
@GET("job/list/slides")
fun getDetailOfSelectedJob(
    @Query("current_job") currentJodId: Int?,
    @Query("limit") jobLimit: Int?,
    @Query("search_in") fetchType: String?
): Single<Response<JobViewResponse>>
```

`JobViewResponse.kt`

```
data class JobViewResponse(
    @SerializedName("data") val data: ArrayList<JobDetail>?
) : BaseResponse()
```

`JobDetail.kt`

```
data class JobDetail(
    @SerializedName("job_id") val jobId: Int,
    @SerializedName("tuition_type") val jobType: String?,
    @SerializedName("class_image") val jobImage: String,
    @SerializedName("salary") val salary: String,
    @SerializedName("no_of_student") val noOfStudent: Int,
    @SerializedName("student_gender") val studentGender: String,
    @SerializedName("tutor_gender") val preferredTutor: String,
    @SerializedName("days_per_week") val daysPerWeek: String?,
    @SerializedName("other_req") val otherReq: String?,
    @SerializedName("latitude") val latitude: Double?,
    @SerializedName("longitude") val longitude: Double?,
    @SerializedName("area") val area: String,
    @SerializedName("tutoring_time") val tutoringTime: String?,
    @SerializedName("posted_date") val postedDate: String?,
    @SerializedName("subjects") val subjects: String,
    @SerializedName("title") val title: String
)
```

`JodSliderDataSource.kt`

```
class JodSliderDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val jobSliderRestApi: JobSliderRestApi
): RxPagingSource<Int, JobDetail>() {

//    override val keyReuseSupported = true

    @ExperimentalPagingApi
    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, JobDetail>): Int? {
        return state.anchorPosition?.let {
            state.closestItemToPosition(it)?.jobId
        }
    }

    override fun loadSingle(params: LoadParams<Int>): Single<LoadResult<Int, JobDetail>> {
        return jobSliderRestApi.getDetailOfSelectedJob(42673, 2, "next").toSingle()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map { jobResponse -> toLoadResult(jobResponse.data) }
            .onErrorReturn { LoadResult.Error(it) }
    }

    private fun toLoadResult(data: ArrayList<JobDetail>): LoadResult<Int, JobDetail> {
        return LoadResult.Page(data = data, prevKey = null, nextKey = data.lastOrNull()?.jobId)
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting nextKey here: `nextKey = data.lastOrNull()?.jobId`. Make sure you're not returning the same key twice here - does your backend API just return the key back to you if there's no more to load? You need to check for that and return `null` in that case.

Comment: @dlam thanks brother for your response. Backend is okey my brother. May be I made any mistake while implementing

Comment: @AminulHaqueAome Hello, Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @amrismail no brother

Comment: @amrismail I'm facing the same issue just wonder if you have a solution

Comment: @a-rohim I forgot about that but I'm using now Paging 3 with jetpack compose and this issue didn't appear. I overrided the `keyReuseSupported` to true and go through google code lab https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-paging#4 and it works well with me.

Comment: good to know will try. thank you! @amrismail

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error and this is what worked for me. In the **JodSliderDataSource** class, **toLoadResult** method, set the **nextKey** parameter value by getting the page number from the response data and adding one.

```
    private fun toLoadResult(
        data: ArrayList<JobDetail>
    ): LoadResult<Int, JobDetail>  {
        return LoadResult.Page(
        data = data, 
        prevKey = null,
        nextKey = data.lastOrNull()?.jobId + 1 // Add one to the page number here.
    )
}
```